# Theme 'theme': No message found under code 'styleSheet' for locale 'en_US'

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Error:
Theme 'theme': No message found under code 'styleSheet' for locale 'en_US'.

This error occurs only on the welcome page (root):
When I use this link:

```
localhost:8080/SpringMVC/
```

On the other pages, this error does not occur
For example:

```
localhost:8080/SpringMVC/index
localhost:8080/SpringMVC/main
localhost:8080/SpringMVC/user/mike
```

If I will remove the code from the header jsp, then this error will disappear

Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code='styleSheet'/>" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in the spring docs:
[link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/ThemeTag.html)

I added an additional parameter to the following code (text):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code='styleSheet'/>" type="text/css"/>
```

After change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code='styleSheet' text=''/>" type="text/css"/>
```

Now if it cannot find the code='styleSheet' it will use the value from "text" field.

This problem occurred only on the root page so I don't know whether there is a better approach to resolve it but for me it's fine.